# Get closest text entry of a list from a string

Tags: nlp

I am trying to build a RNN model for text classification and I am currently building my dataset.
I am trying to do some of the work automatically and I'm using an API that gets me some information for each text I send to it.
So basically :
I have, for each text on my dataframe, I have a df['label'] that contain a 1 to 3 word string.
I have a list of vocabulary (my futur classes) and for each on the df['label'] item, and want to attribute one of the vocabulary list item, depending on which is closest in meaning.
So I need to measure how close each of the labels are close in meaning to my vocabulary list.
Any help ?

Comment: Imho it's very risky to assign gold standard labels automatically, you cannot be sure that the labels are correct and you cannot properly evaluate the model since you don't have good test data either. Imho you should at least have a subset checked manually.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid labelling my dataset manually, but looks like I am not going to escape it x)